# How do you delay an click event on a link (with a _blank target) and still have the new tab open?

Tags: javascript

I have link like this:

```
<a id="blerg_event" href="/berlg" target="_blank">Berlg!</a>
```

I want to run some js before the user leaves the page when clicking on this link (auto-saving some data if you we're wondering)...

If I catch the event like this...

```
$("#blerg_event").click(function(){

var href = $(this).attr("href");

//callback to do link after saving data...
do_somthing(function(){
    window.open(href, "_blank");
}); 

return false;
});
```

This caused a browser warning about a pop-up. Obviously the browser thinks I'm a spammy site opening stuff in the background.

How do run some js and then open the link in a new tab without causing a warning?

Comment: Since you are using target=_blank, the user is not leaving your page – so I can’t see why you have to “wait” for the data to be saved.

Comment: @CBroe Because the data that's being saved is used on the new page that is opening. It's a sort of preview of the stuff you're working on. So it does need to be saved.

Comment: Well then you could open only a “dummy” page in the popup immediately (and catch the return value of window.open to have a reference to the popup window), and once your JS operation is complete, redirect inside the popup to the real target page that displays the preview via `popupreference.location.href="…"`. (Btw., how is that still a “preview” if you are already _saving_ the data?)

Comment: @CBroe That worked brilliantly thanks! Pop it as an answer if you like. I think you'd need to see the app as to why I'm doing it (it's sort a rendered preview of some data models you're opening up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could open only a “dummy” page in the popup immediately (and catch the return value of window.open to have a reference to the popup window), and once your JS operation is complete, redirect inside the popup to the real target page that displays the preview via `popupreference.location.href="…"`.